# Restrict User Access to only upload & view their own files in a SharePoint Site

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions

I'm trying to restrict user access on a SharePoint site. This user must be able to upload to SharePoint and view their own files, but they cannot have access to see any other folders or files.

There doesn't seem to be an easy way to do this in permissions, and add & view access allows them to see everyone's uploads. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a workaround, you could use go to Library Settings -> Versioning settings -> Set "Require Check Out" as "Yes".

When users upload files for the first time, don't check in files. At this time, they can only see their own files.